# TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null. at myFunction(Code:6)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Log I can see app has been defined as SpreadsheetApp, but the getActiveSpreadsheet() is returning null.  which in turn causes the getActiveSheet() to say it cannot call method with null.

I've already tried clearing my browser history, opening a new blank spreadsheet but get same error.

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
    Logger.log(app);
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    Logger.log(ss);
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null. at myFunction(Code:6)

Comment: Please provide more context on what you are trying to do so that your question can be easier to understand.

Comment: How are you accessing the script file where your code is executed? Do you open it by clicking on Tools -> Script Editor inside your spreadsheet or is it a standalone Apps Script file?

Comment: It is a standalone Apps Script file.

Comment: So I used the Tools > Script Editor inside my spreadsheet, and copied the code into a new script and it worked of course.  So now that I've written some Apps Scripts as standalone, how do I use them in spreadsheets I open later that aren't tied to this code?

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem:

You're trying to run standalone scripts as if they're bound to a spreadsheet. (using `getActive...`)

From the Class Spreadsheet Documentation:

> Functions that are run in the context of a spreadsheet can get a reference to the corresponding Spreadsheet object by calling this function.

---

#### Options:

1. Bind your script to a spreadsheet by opening a sheet and going to `Tools > Script Editor`, then running it from there.
2. Instead of using `getActiveSpreadsheet()`, use `SpreadsheetApp.openById('id')` or `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('url')` instead. These will open the spreadsheet by its unique ID or URL and can be used from standalone scripts.

---

#### References:

1. [Class `SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
2. [`getActiveSpreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet())
3. [`openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))
4. [`openByUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)