# Google Apps Script - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror

It's late and I've been working on this for a while, I had a version of this working on another google sheet, but in that one I was only trying to work with one sheet at a time. This time, I'm trying to call ranges from multiple sheets and I think I'm just doing it wrong... I appreciate any help, but no matter how I try to arrange this I keep getting "Cannot read property 'getRange' of null like I'm calling absolutely nothing. :\

Edit [(adding doc link)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KpVh2Q7rewSrGRHBvZWl3DWqvyIGiVvX1n0L3aDfSw4/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function onTrigger() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Routed Options')
      .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
      .addToUi();
}

function AddRoutedOptions() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.alert(
      'Add all Routed tasks to the Project Tracker?',
      'Are you sure you want to add all Routed tasks to the Project Tracker?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
  var gs1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Getting Started Checklist');
  var mp1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Mid-Point Checklist'); 
  var pg1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Pre-Go Live Checklist');
  var vc1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Video Course Checklist');
  gs1.getRange('B29:B30').copyTo(gs1.getRange('E20:E21'), {contentsOnly:true});
  gs1.getRange('B31').copyTo(gs1.getRange('H18'), {contentsOnly:true});
  mp1.getRange('B28:B31').copyTo(mp1.getRange('B21:B24'), {contentsOnly:true});
  mp1.getRange('B32:B33').copyTo(mp1.getRange('E12:E13'), {contentsOnly:true});
  mp1.getRange('B34').copyTo(mp1.getRange('H18'), {contentsOnly:true});
  pg1.getRange('B32:B35').copyTo(pg1.getRange('E25:E28'), {contentsOnly:true});
  vc1.getRange('B32:C37').copyTo(vc1.getRange('G10:H15'), {contentsOnly:true});
} else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('No tasks were added.');
  }
}

function RemoveRoutedOptions() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.alert(
      'Remove all Routed tasks from the Project Tracker?',
      'Are you sure you want to remove all Routed tasks from the Project Tracker?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
  var gs1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Getting Started Checklist')
  var mp1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Mid-Point Checklist')
  var pg1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Pre-Go Live Checklist')
  var vc1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Video Course Checklist')
  gs1.getRange('E20:E21').clearContent()
  mp1.getRange('B21:B24').clearContent()
  pg1.getRange('E25:E28').clearContent()
  vc1.getRange('G10:H15').clearContent()
} else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('No tasks were removed.')
  }
}
```

Comment: I've since reviewed the docs [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741432/typeerror-cannot-call-method-getactivesheet-of-null-at-myfunctioncode6) and tried to be more specific by using SpreadsheetApp.openByID with the rest of my code by that didn't work either. :(

Comment: In AddRoutedOptions(), there are several calls to getRange(). Have you figured out which call is causing the error? In general, I think it is caused by the wrong sheet name. Do the sheet names really exist in the active spreadsheet?

Comment: If you would try to create a [mcve] which is smaller than your current code you'll probably be able to solve your own problem.  But atleast then you might have a better chance of attracting more help.  Currently the problem involves too many ranges for most of us to consider setting up for ourselves.  I might do it for my own problems but doing it for someone else is not very likely.

Comment: @IncluCat yes, I've made sure the sheet names exist and that there is no whitespace at the end of the names. I've added a test document now to my original question which may help with context and the problem I'm having. ty for your help and response.

Comment: @Cooper sorry about that and valid point. I've since edited my question and added a test document that should fully replicate what I'm trying to do. All of the code is in SecondaryCode.gs. 

Essentially when the Remove option is chosen it should remove all the selected data where I'm using .getRange. When I use the Add option it should pull data from one part of the sheet using .getRange and then .copyTo specific cells as outlined. 

I realize I'm not great at commenting things in my own code until I'm done so I wanted to give a breakdown. Thanks in advance for your help and feedback

Answer (score 0):

Well good news, is I fixed my problem and got it working but I don't know that I understand why, so if anyone can still help me point that out I'd appreciate it. All it came down to was changing the part after my "var"s to sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4 etc instead of gs1, mp1, pg1, vc1. I don't know why the latter wouldn't work though, that's literally all I changed and it works perfectly...

Does the first thing after the "var" HAVE to be sheet? It can't be a value of our own or did I just call it wrong? Sorry very new to app script, still learning a lot!

```
function AddRoutedOptions() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.alert(
      'Add all Routed tasks to the Project Tracker?',
      'Are you sure you want to add all Routed tasks to the Project Tracker?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Getting Started Checklist');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Mid-Point Checklist');
  var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Pre-Go Live Checklist');
  var sheet4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Video Course Checklist');
    sheet1.getRange('B29:B30').copyTo(sheet1.getRange('E20:E21'), {contentsOnly:true});
    sheet1.getRange('B31').copyTo(sheet1.getRange('H18'), {contentsOnly:true});
    sheet2.getRange('B28:B31').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('B21:B24'), {contentsOnly:true});
    sheet2.getRange('B32:B33').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('E12:E13'), {contentsOnly:true});
    sheet2.getRange('B34').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('H18'), {contentsOnly:true});
    sheet3.getRange('B32:B35').copyTo(sheet3.getRange('E25:E28'), {contentsOnly:true});
    sheet4.getRange('B32:C37').copyTo(sheet4.getRange('G10:H15'), {contentsOnly:true});
} else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('No tasks were added.');
  }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to use StackOverflow as a forum-like community. Stackoverflow does not work this way - it is FAQ style database of "Question->Answer" pairs. I bet nobody will look for your new questions asked in a answer so they will stay unanswered. I suggest you to [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [check help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to get familiar with what Stackoverflow is and how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the additional information.
I ran your script in debug mode, and I found the `vc1` became null.
In your spreadsheet, there is a sheet named `Video Course List` but you're passing `Video Course Checklist` to the getSheetByName().
Please check the names.

[image]